# Howto use svelte.js in PhpStorm/WebStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, svelte, svelte-3

I tried to find the answer myself, but couldn't find any tutorials or checklists.

What is required to use PhpStorm or WebStorm to develop with Svelte.js?

Answer (score 2):

1. Install the [Svelte plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12375-svelte).
2. Follow [WEB-27366](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-27366).
3. MDN: [Getting started with Svelte](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Client-side_JavaScript_frameworks/Svelte_getting_started).